# Division sometimes breaks syntax highlighting in ruby-mode

Tags: spacemacs, syntax-highlighting, ruby-mode

Interesting bug in ruby-mode. When a variable called `index` is followed by a slash `/`, syntax highlighting breaks.

Here's a screenshot to show you what I mean:

[image: fun syntax highlighting bug in ruby-mode]

I'm not really sure how to file a ticket on the ruby-mode repo since I've never used SVN. Anyone know where to go from here?

Comment: To report a bug in ruby-mode, you should `M-x report-emacs-bug`. ruby-mode is distributed with Emacs. I can reproduce the problem, but the way to fix it is non-obvious, and it doesn't seem inappropriate to have that discussion in StackExchange. Thanks.

Comment: `it doesn't seem inappropriate to have that discussion in StackExchange`. Was that an intentional double-negative? Are you saying it *is* appropriate to have that discussion here?

Comment: Right, sorry. It was a result of a sloppy edit.

Comment: Interestingly it only happens with `index`, if you change the var's name is goes ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news everyone!

This is now fixed upstream, and will be in the next Emacs release (29.2).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why distinguishing between a method on a string and a variable name is ambiguous. Wouldn't any variable name that also happens to be a method on a literal be problematic, in that case?

Comment: Also, I am going to submit a bug report.

Comment: The ambiguity I'm referring to here is between regexp delimiters and division.

Comment: Upvotes are nice and all, but would somebody file the bug?

Comment: Filed the bug with `M-x report-emacs-bug` last week, right after creating this post.

Comment: @harumph Do you have a bug number? Or, better, a URL?

Comment: I do not, and I can't find it in the bug tracker. First time filing an emacs bug, maybe I messed something up. I'll try again.

Comment: @harumph Are you using Mac Port, by any chance? It hijacks the bug reporting mechanism, and never forwards any reports to the official list.

Comment: using homebrew.

Comment: Homebrew allows installing different versions.

Comment: In any case, when you report a bug, you should get a reply email with the link to the created bug. No need to look for the bug tracker.

Comment: I'm running 24.5.1. Sent again, but no response yet.

Comment: You're either running the NS port, or the Mac Port. There are probably articles on the Internet that tell how to tell which one you have.

Comment: Just want to add that I couldn't find the bug report if you did add it, and sent one in myself: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=67569

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if you use `enh-ruby-mode`, that problem doesn't occur.

https://github.com/zenspider/enhanced-ruby-mode